# how to make the right side navigation menu to left side

Tags: menu, navigation

I want to use this html template http://www.grouporigin.com/clients/upload/infinity/index.html to create my website. I want to make the top navigation menu transition in the left side with the same effect. Please tell me how i can change the navigation menu transition from the right to the left side.

Comment: #menu-nav-wrap {
line-height: 1.6;padding: 3.6rem 3rem;height: 100%;width: 240px; position: fixed;right: 0; top: 0;visibility: hidden;overflow-y: auto; z-index: 800;-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); -ms-transform: translateX(100%); transform: translateX(100%); -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; }

Comment: this the css being used by the right side navigation menu

Comment: I tried changing right:0 to left:0 but it is not working properly.

Comment: Experts please help me to fix this.

Comment: hi, please someone kindly tell me if it is possible to do. That will be a great help to me

Comment: I found the answer, it is -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);-ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);